# how to develop Azure CSP billing Api in azure functions using .net core

Tags: azure, api, billing, azure-function-app, azure-billing-api

I am trying to develop an API for azure billing for CSP in azure functions using .net core 3
any guidance will be appreciated.

how do I call a billing API from the azure function?

Comment: Can you provide what steps you have taken or tried?

Comment: I created an azure function (sample http triggered) and then deployed on azure, now I am stuck on how to make a call to billing api sorry i m new to azure

Comment: I need to get the consumption data using the partner center Rest API

Answer (score 0):

**install with powershell:**

`Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Billing`

**code example:**

```
/* Include these directives
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Billing;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Billing.Models;
*/

// Log into Azure
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);
var billingClient = new BillingClient(serviceCreds);
billingClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

// Get list of invoices
billingClient.Invoices.List();
```

Just follow below steps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/billing

Above code is based on C#, you need to create a AAD app register first.

Comment: I am trying to run above code but BillingClient class is not present in  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Billing package can you help me on this?